# Wordpress Won't Keep My Url Params

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm working on WP website and anytime I add url params to the url, it redirects the page to a version without the params.

Example:

http://mysite.com/?foo=bar -> redirects to -> http://mysite.com/

http://mysite.com/contact-us/?foo=bar -> redirects to http://mysite.com/contact-us/

How can I fix this? We need certain params to load with the page for various reasons.

**Contents of .htaccess (edited to add QSA - which isn't working):**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: put here content of .htaccess file please

Comment: Temporarily deactivate all plugins and the non-default theme. Try again. Does it still redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `query_vars` to make that happen. WordPress stores all the query string parameters that it may need in a global object and it ignores everything else.

You need to instruct it to do the following:

- Instruct WordPress to save your variables. You add a filter to `query_vars` to do that. An example is given in the link below.
- Retrieve your data using `$wp_query->query_vars['customvariable']` instead of the regular `_GET` or `_POST`.

The details can be found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries#Custom_Archives

Comment: This isn't the answer. This assumes that the page actually gets to load with the url params. My app is redirecting them away before it gets a chance to load.

Comment: AFAIK the `query_vars` happens before the page load takes place. If your parameter is not present in the `query_vars` array, WordPress will ignore it and will read the rest of the URL and parse it. Also, the URL on the browser does change because WordPress does do a set of redirects before your page's shown - so, I believe your parameter will not show in the URL irrespective of it's status in `query_vars`   - depending on your choice of permalink.

Comment: I was mistaken before — I think Adhip is correct here. WP deletes unrecognized GET parameters by default, so you need to tell it not to. See http://www.webopius.com/content/137/using-custom-url-parameters-in-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Add the "query string append" (`QSA`) flag to the end of your rewrite rules.

> 'qsappend|`QSA`' (**q**uery **s**tring **a**ppend) This flag forces the rewrite
>   engine to append a query string part of the substitution string to the
>   existing string, instead of replacing it. Use this when you want to
>   add more data to the query string via a rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA]

# Without QSA: http://mysite.com/contact-us/?foo=bar →
#   http://mysite.com/index.php?page_name=contact-us
# With QSA: http://mysite.com/contact-us/?foo=bar →
#   http://mysite.com/index.php?page_name=contact-us&foo=bar
```

See the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule) for more information.

Comment: Hmm. Which one - there are a lot of them. The W3TC Page Cache core rules are auto generated. I'm a bit skeptical about touching this. Could I just add them to the WordPress rules?

Comment: Yes, I think just adding to the WP ones would be fine.

Comment: This isn't working: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress